# Usage of Non-SDK interfaces. Desugaring

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, jdk-desugaring

I am checking my app in Firebase, before sending it to Play Store, and I receive this warnings:

```
Usage of non-SDK interfaces
Ljava/util/Collections$SynchronizedCollection;-><init>(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
Ljava/util/Collections$SynchronizedCollection;->mutex:Ljava/lang/Object;
Ljava/util/Collections$SynchronizedCollection;->c:Ljava/util/Collection;
Ljava/util/Collections$SynchronizedSet;-><init>(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

They are marked in hiddenapi_flags as "greylist-max-o".
I have isolated the problem and noticed than the problem is when using Desugaring library (I included it to use some Time features as ZonedDateTime, ZoneOffset,etc in Api<26).
My question is: With these warnings can I update the app to Google Play? Is there any alternative, in older Apis, to use similar functions to ZonedDateTime.getAvailableZoneIds and so?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I sent the question to Issuetracker.google.com and they are investigating the issue. This is their answer:

COMMENTS
All comments
sg...@google.comsg...@google.com #2May 17, 2023 11:02AM

> This is caused by the code in DesugarCollections.java. The code is
> trying to acquire the lock of the underlying SynchronizedCollection
> through reflection of fields and methods which are internal to the
> platform.
>
> If this reflection does not succeed, then the methods removeIf,
> forEach, replaceAll and sort will access the internal collection field
> directly.
>
> According to the hiddenapi-flags.csv the mutex field is not accessible
> after Android 8.
>
> This is not optimal, and could lead to undefined behavior. I suggest
> that you avoid using SynchronizedCollection and instead use concurrent
> data structures if at all possible.

sg...@google.comsg...@google.com #3May 17, 2023 11:04AM

> Tested the following code on emulators, and it succeeds on Android
> O_MR1 and fails on Android P. ALso tested on an Android U phone where
> it also fails.

```
public class SynchronizedCollectionReflection {
    public static String test() {
        Class<? extends Collection> SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION;
        SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>()).getClass();
        Class<? extends List> SYNCHRONIZED_LIST;
        SYNCHRONIZED_LIST = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>()).getClass();
        Field MUTEX_FIELD;
        MUTEX_FIELD = getField(SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION, "mutex");
        if (MUTEX_FIELD != null) {
            MUTEX_FIELD.setAccessible(true);
        } else {
            return "Failed MUTEX_FIELD";
        }
        Field COLLECTION_FIELD;
        COLLECTION_FIELD = getField(SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION, "c");
        if (COLLECTION_FIELD != null) {
            COLLECTION_FIELD.setAccessible(true);
        } else {
            return "Failed COLLECTION_FIELD";
        }
        Class<? extends Set> synchronizedSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()).getClass();
        Constructor<? extends Set> SYNCHRONIZED_SET_CONSTRUCTOR;
        SYNCHRONIZED_SET_CONSTRUCTOR = getConstructor(synchronizedSet, Set.class, Object.class);
        if (SYNCHRONIZED_SET_CONSTRUCTOR != null) {
            SYNCHRONIZED_SET_CONSTRUCTOR.setAccessible(true);
        } else {
            return "Failed SYNCHRONIZED_SET_CONSTRUCTOR";
        }
        Constructor<? extends Collection> SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION_CONSTRUCTOR;
        SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION_CONSTRUCTOR =
                getConstructor(SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION, Collection.class, Object.class);
        if (SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION_CONSTRUCTOR != null) {
            SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION_CONSTRUCTOR.setAccessible(true);
        } else {
            return "Failed SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION_CONSTRUCTOR";
        }
        return "SUCCESS!";
    }

    private static Field getField(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // For Desugar: Some fields are not available on instrumented devices.
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static <E> Constructor<? extends E> getConstructor(
            Class<? extends E> clazz, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // For Desugar: Some constructors are not available on instrumented devices.
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

sg...@google.comsg...@google.com #4May 17, 2023 11:05AM
Reassigned to cl...@google.com.

> We should take another look at this, and consider failing the
> operations which cannot be safely desugared.